# Is it possible connect 4 HC-SR04(for every direction) in a 170 Points Mini Breadboard (SYB-170)?

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++, bread-board, nodemcu-build

I need to connect four HC-SR04 (Ultrasonic distance sensor) in a 170 Points Mini Breadboard SYB-170.
Each sensor for each direction(North,South,East,West)

I am attaching the image of both components, sensor as well as the breadboard.Also I am using Nodemcu esp8266
Kindly help!

[HC-SR04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvalT.png) ,
[170 Points Mini Breadboard (SYB-170)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV7Sy.png)

I don't know how to connect them.

kindly attach the image of the connection